# Unable to get eigen library to start working in clion

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen, clion

I am trying to work with matrixes using eigen library,

Below is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(Laser_ablation_nanoparticles)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

set(EIGEN_DIR "C:/Users/Vishal/Documents/Academic documents/MSc/Manchester/dissertation/Eigen/eigen-3.4.0")
if(NOT EXISTS ${EIGEN_DIR})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Please check that the set Eigen directory is valid!")
endif()

include_directories(${EIGEN_DIR})

add_executable(Laser_ablation_nanoparticles main.cpp)
```

I get the Cmake output

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.1.5\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.1.5/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -G Ninja -S C:\Users\Vishal\CLionProjects\Laser_ablation_nanoparticles -B C:\Users\Vishal\CLionProjects\Laser_ablation_nanoparticles\cmake-build-debug
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Vishal/CLionProjects/Laser_ablation_nanoparticles/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

But when I run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream theFile("id-area-3.txt");
    int id;
    //int column;
    float area;
    //double tarea;

    while (theFile >> id >> area)
        cout << id << " , " << area << "|";

}
```

I get the following error

```
====================[ Build | Laser_ablation_nanoparticles | Debug ]============
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.1.5\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Vishal\CLionProjects\Laser_ablation_nanoparticles\cmake-build-debug --target Laser_ablation_nanoparticles -j 6
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Laser_ablation_nanoparticles.dir/main.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/Laser_ablation_nanoparticles.dir/main.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.5\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE  -I"C:/Users/Vishal/Documents/Academic documents/MSc/Manchester/dissertation/Eigen/eigen-3.4.0" -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -std=gnu++23 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Laser_ablation_nanoparticles.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\Laser_ablation_nanoparticles.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/Laser_ablation_nanoparticles.dir/main.cpp.obj -c C:/Users/Vishal/CLionProjects/Laser_ablation_nanoparticles/main.cpp
C:/Users/Vishal/CLionProjects/Laser_ablation_nanoparticles/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <Eigen/Core>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Although the Eigen library is visible in  external libraries , I am unable to use it

[Screen shot of clion external librarties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOY04.png)

Comment: use `find_package(Eigen3)` like [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html)

Comment: Do you have the file `C:/Users/Vishal/Documents/Academic documents/MSc/Manchester/dissertation/Eigen/eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/Core`? If not, then your specification of Eigen3 include directory (`EIGEN_DIR` variable) is incorrect.

Comment: @vsh : I have tried this but i am confused as how do i set the directory

Comment: @tsyvarev , it is a folder called Eigen in Eigen 3.4.0 but when I try to use the Eigen-3.4.0/Eigen, it throws me an error that it is not able to find Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

Comment: @VishalPatil something like `set(Eigen3_DIR path/to/eigen3/cmake/)` or `-DEigen3_DIR=path/to/eigen3/cmake/` in cmake's invocation